# Getting error while writing output to Microsoft Excel programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, excel, export-to-excel

I developed a winforms application using C# in .NET 4.0, in which end user selects an input Excel file. The program then generates an output Excel file with extra cells based on business logic of my application.

After selecting the input file and run my application, If i open any other excel sheets on my machine, then i see the output excel file being still written in Read Only mode and if i close the opened excel file then my application is throwing an error.

How to stop the read only excel sheet getting opened before the entire output is completely written?

Comment: Win Forms. I assume you are using a .Net language. C#? VB.Net? How about a sample of your source? What version of Excel? What version of Framework? We need just enought info to reasonably reproduce your problem, and then you will have people flock to answer you.

Comment: @TimWagaman: It said C# at the end of the title :)

Comment: Ah, and so shows my limited attention span when reading a title.

Comment: Yeah, The application is developed in C#, Framework version is 4.0.

Comment: You are opening excel file, processing it and saving as output. There may be good chance of conflict between input and output file. First save input file as a new (output) file, close the input and then open the output file, process the same and save it again. If you will provide the code, it would be better to understand and resolve the issue.

Comment: @ArunSingh, Thank you for the suggestions.. Resolved the issue following your tweaks.. :)